# GCM Token validation

Tags: java, android, sencha-touch, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am little bit confused in validating the GCM token. I am working in cross platform application using Sencha framework and my server side is in Java. I have a query regarding how to validate the registration ID (GCM token)? Is there any specific API to validate the GCM token? Can you guide me how to handle this, either in client side or server side? I have already did registration part in server side, where user can register their GCM token in database. Now I need to validate this registration token.

Is unregistering the application every 2 weeks a good approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for solving the GCM validation using canonicalID
[link](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/samples/gcm-demo-server/src/com/google/android/gcm/demo/server/SendAllMessagesServlet.java?name=gcm-1.0.2)

```
 private void asyncSend(List<String> partialDevices) {
    // make a copy
    final List<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>(partialDevices);
    threadPool.execute(new Runnable() {

      public void run() {
        Message message = new Message.Builder().build();
        MulticastResult multicastResult;
        try {
          multicastResult = sender.send(message, devices, 5);
        } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Error posting messages", e);
          return;
        }
        List<Result> results = multicastResult.getResults();
        // analyze the results
        for (int i = 0; i < devices.size(); i++) {
          String regId = devices.get(i);
          Result result = results.get(i);
          String messageId = result.getMessageId();
          if (messageId != null) {
            logger.fine("Succesfully sent message to device: " + regId +
                "; messageId = " + messageId);
            String canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalRegistrationId();
            if (canonicalRegId != null) {
              // same device has more than on registration id: update it
              logger.info("canonicalRegId " + canonicalRegId);
              Datastore.updateRegistration(regId, canonicalRegId);
            }
          } else {
            String error = result.getErrorCodeName();
            if (error.equals(Constants.ERROR_NOT_REGISTERED)) {
              // application has been removed from device - unregister it
              logger.info("Unregistered device: " + regId);
              Datastore.unregister(regId);
            } else {
              logger.severe("Error sending message to " + regId + ": " + error);
            }
          }
        }
      }});
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

You register to GCM and un-register from GCM in the client side. That's where you get the registration ID from Google.

Once you have a registration ID, you should consider it valid until :

1. You send a message with the registration ID to Google's GCM Server and get a NotRegistered or InvalidRegistration error. In these cases you should remove the registration ID from your DB.
2. You send a message with the registration ID to Google's GCM Server and get a successful response, but the response contains a canonical registration ID. In this case you should replace the registration ID with the canonical registration ID.
3. The app explicitly un-registered from GCM, and notified the server about it, in which case you should remove the registration ID from your DB.

I don't see any point in un-registering the app every two weeks. Google's code samples only re-register the app once a new version of it is installed, and even then they don't un-register before re-registering.

Comment: Yeah this is the exact solution. Getting the canonical reg id and replace with old one.

Comment: Can u explain when i will get canonical id because the current registration id is valid for 7 days. Right now i am tracking of canonical id in my server

Comment: The current registration ID is not valid for 7 days. Google may decide to refresh the registration ID from time to time. That's why they posted a demo app that considered the registration ID invalid after 7 days, but last time I checked they removed that condition from the demo. If you register to GCM and get a new registration ID, you should send it to your server, to update the DB. If you don't, the server might get a canonical registration ID in the response from Google, and modify the DB then.